# How to close the angular bootstrap typeahead programmatically with a shortcut

Tags: angularjs, accessibility, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm working on angular bootstrap typeahead keyboard accessibility. I'm trying to provide keyboard support as provided [here](http://oaa-accessibility.org/example/10/).

On hitting Alt + (Up / Down), Typeahead should be expanded if closed and vice versa.
I'm able to expand the typeahead, when closed (clearing the view value). After closing, focus should be on the typeahead, so that user can edit it further
But I'm not able to close the typeahead, when it is opened.

Can someone suggest me how to complete this.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to fake the event that closes the dropdown.

If you are using jQuery, just do:

```
$(typeahead).trigger('blur');
```

Comment: Focus should be on the typeahead, and allow the user to edit it. So cannot do this

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean here. How this would prevent the user from edit it?
My suggestion was to execute the line of code On hitting Alt + (Up / Down)

Comment: When you blur it, focus is going out of the typeahead. I tried it again just now to confirm.

Comment: Ok, got it. Then maybe destroy (`$(typeahead).typeahead('destroy');`) and then re-generate it. OR empty its source (`$(typeahead).typeahead({source: ''});`) and then re-fill it.

Comment: is this is angular bootstrap?

Comment: It is bootstrap typeahead but there are chances that it works. 
Otherwise, I just had a look at the [doc](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#typeahead) and typeahead-is-open seems to be what you need, isn't it?

Comment: typeahead-is-open won't work for this. Its like one way. It tells if the typeahead is open, it won't take the action based on the value we set

Comment: What about the other suggestions?

Comment: which suggestions? your destroy idea? I have still not tried it. Will try and let you know. I'm not sure what to pass for $(<typeahead>), is it the id of the element?

Comment: Yes, just regular jQuery element finder

Comment: this is what i'm getting "TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function".
I tried this, $("#stateDropDown").typeahead("destroy");

Comment: Ok, then it will become complicated, can you create a plunkr?

Comment: Doing `$('[uib-typeahead-popup]').toggle();` on line 40 works and you can skip the condition on line 39.

Comment: Updated the plunker. It is closing the dropdown, but the focus is not returned to the input (Not able to type anything in the textbox). I tried removing the whole condition, but then it is not working, so just updated in open case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157661/discussion-between-nicolas-s-and-sanjay).